# Amazon redshift stored procedure, CONTINUE cannot be used outside a loop;

Tags: amazon-redshift

Im building a stored procedure in amazon redshift.
This is an example of what im trying to do.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test_sp1()
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
DECLARE v_test RECORD;
BEGIN
FOR v_test IN select * from pg_user
  LOOP
    RAISE INFO 'before loop';
    CONTINUE;
    RAISE INFO 'after loop';
  END LOOP;
END;
$$;
CALL test_sp1();
```

This piece of code gives me an exception 
"[42601][500310] Amazon Invalid operation: CONTINUE cannot be used outside a loop".

Why can i not use continue in this loop?

Comment: Why are you putting a `LOOP` within a `FOR`? `CONTINUE` would be used to exit from a nested loop. Doing a Continue in a single loop just means the loop would run again, which doesn't seem to make sense. What are you actually wanting to accomplish?

Comment: It's just an example. In reality my sp is different and very long, but the problem with continue is similar.

Answer (score 0):

The error appears to be happening when CONTINUE passes control to the beginning of the loop but there's no more iterating to be done.